# Does the pointwise limit of a $W^{r,p}$- bounded sequence belong to $W^{r,p}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $f_n,f:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R$ such that
$$ f_n(x)\to f(x) \textrm{ for a.e. }x$$
as $n\to\infty$.
Let $p\in(1,\infty)$, $r\in\mathbb N$. Suppose that there exists a constant $C\in[0,\infty)$ such that
$$ \|f_n\|_{W^{r,p}} \leq C$$
for every $n\in\mathbb N\,$.
Can I conclude that $f\in W^{r,p}$ ?

Comment: Yes, because pointwise a.e. and weak limits of $L^p$-functions coincide (apply this to all derivatives of the $W^{r,p} function)

Comment: @daw would you like to explain this in an answer? Maybe just taking $r=1$

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2228013/weak-convergence-for-subsequence-pointwise-a-e-convergence-for-the-full-seque?rq=1